# Encrypting database password in spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, encryption

I am trying to encrypt password which i have store in spring.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<context:annotation-config/>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.prakash" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" alue="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/HibernateStudy" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
</bean>
```

I googled I got to know that this is possible using [jasypt Package](http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html) . But somehow I am not able to integrate it in my application.
Can Anyone please help me.

I know that i can replace the line `<property name="password" value="mypassword" />` with `<property name="password" value= ENC(2Cu5057YZbQcUQ8cUQQMinzMDD2GeSXh) />`

After that wht i should do?. Do i have to create any object in java file or something.. 
Can anyone please give  me a working flow for this jasypt package with its x.ml file and java file.

Thank You

[Update] 
Hi All,
Now I am bale to read connect the database using encryption password, But the password used for decrypt the password is passed from environment variable. Is there any other way to pass it .

my updated spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<context:annotation-config/>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.prakash" />



<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
 class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
<property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
<property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>

                                                                   -->
<bean id="configurationEncryptor"
 class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
<property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>


<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
<property name="locations">
 <list>
   <value>database.properties</value>
 </list>
</property>

</bean>

<bean
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/HibernateStudy" />
    <property name="username" value="${connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${connection.encrypt}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />



</bean>
```

Comment: How have you configured the encrypter? There must be a bean of your classpath to decrypt these passwords, and that bean needs to know the decryption password. See [the documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html#Integrating_jasypt_with_Springs_application_configuration_infrastructure).

Comment: Thank You for pointing. Now I am able to connect to database using encrypted password. Here I am able to read the data from password by using the environment variable. Is there any other way to pass the encryption password.

Comment: The answer here is "just don't". Supply the password, or even the entire connection string, externally, as from an environment variable. Spring Boot or Spring Cloud Connectors make it simple.

Answer (score -2):

You can also hardcode password at class file and assign to bean as well.

```
    .. 
<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
                   <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
                   <property name="password" value="#Key.keyValue}" />
         </bean>
    ..
```

Where Key.keyValue is Static method of Key class.

Comment: This looks more appropriate. Can you please give me the code example for doing this.

Comment: @Prak may I ask what purpose the encryption would serve if the password is also in the program? The benefit of using this encryption module is dubious at best - the benefit of using the module when its password is stored in the same place as the cyphertext is **absolutely none**.

Comment: This is an appalling idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Let me explain my envoirnment. I have an application where we are connecting it to database using spring.xml configuration. I cannot store the password in that spring.xml file as it can be read by any other user too.( We have some other users is our application too). Also storing key in the spring.xml is not good in my case as it can be read  the same way the password for DB from spring.xml. If the key I can store in class, the shipped application will have the class in binary format which will be safe some what in comparison to plain text format.

Comment: @Prak completely untrue. First, even in machine code strings can be trivially read. Second, Java compiles to **JVM bytecode** - this can be decompiled to the original code and the password read without any effort whatsoever. **Never package passwords in code**.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Thank You pointing it out. Completely agree with you.  I Will discuss it with our team.

Comment: @Boris you are right. by this approach we can only move visible password text to 1 step ahead.